# JQUERY menu collapse or slidedown

Tags: jquery, html, menu

Can someone tell me what is the name of the effect this top main menu is using [here](http://www.graffdiamonds.com/#/about/company)?

Collapse menu? Slide down menu?
I'm trying to find a script that can do the same effect/transition!

Thank you.

Comment: That website is using flash but you can recreate it in CSS using :hover state transitions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

(Beside it's a Flash web) It's called `.animate()` by simply animating the element top position on `.hover()`.

And [here](http://jsbin.com/AlAnazid/1/edit) is an example how to do it in jQuery.

```
$(function(){

  $('#top').hover(function( e ){
    $(this).stop().animate({top: e.type.match('t') ? 0:-50 });
  });

});
```

Also:

```
  var top = [-50,0];
  $('#top').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({top: top.reverse()[0] });
  });
```

```
  $('#top').hover(function( e ){
    $(this).stop().animate({top: e.type=='mouseenter'? 0 : -50 });
  });
```

```
  $('#top').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({top: 0 });
  }, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({top: -50 });
  });
```